# How can I code sign an Ionic app using Bitrise

Tags: ionic-framework, bitrise

I'm using Bitrise to build an Ionic app.  How can I easily do the complicated code signing part for apple developer so the app can be deployed to iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add Your Apple ID to Xcode**

Start Xcode

Click Xcode > Preferences

At the top of the window select Accounts.

Click on the + on the lower left corner and select Add Apple ID...

A dialog will appear. Add your Apple ID and your password, then select Sign in.

(If you don't have an account you can create an Apple ID by selecting Create Apple ID)

**Export your Apple ID Certificates**

Click Xcode > Preferences

Select your Apple ID and your team

Click Manage Certificates

Right-Click on each certificate and click Export Certificate

**Create an Xcode app by adding the platform to the Ionic project**

Clone your Ionic app

Open your cloned project folder in terminal

Run `ionic cordova platform add ios`

After the platform is added go to the project folder, then: platforms/ios/PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj

Double click on the project to open it in Xcode

**Create an AppID with Apple**

Go to: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

Create a new App

Restart Xcode

Click on the Top-Level Project Name in Xcode

In the 'Signing' section click on 'Team' and choose a team

**Create a Provisioning Profile with Apple**

Go to: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/create

Create a Provisioning Profile

**Download Provisioning Profile with Xcode**

Select Xcode > Preferences menu.

At the top of the window select Accounts.

Select your Apple ID and your team, then select Download Manual Profiles.

Go to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ and your profiles should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to mention that once you generate the Xcode project (`ionic cordova platform add ios`) it's possible to use all the other bitrise.io features designed to use that, e.g. the "iOS Auto Provisioning" one which updates the prov profiles automatically after an apple dev login: https://blog.bitrise.io/ios-auto-provision-step

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  Because the Platforms folder shouldn't be in git for an ionic project.  Your iOS Auto Provisioning tool requires the Platforms folder in order to work.  And the Auto Provisioning step has to run in Bitrise before Ionic Build which creates the Platforms folder.  If you PM me I'll send you the chat where Jozsef and I tried to make this work :-)